# Web scrape without use of browser control?

Tags: c#, vb.net, html-agility-pack

I have a SharePoint site that I currently have a webscrape tool using written in VB and using the web browser control.  It's unbelievably slow and I am looking to update it.  Can we use some toolkits such as HTMLAgilityPack to load a document into DOM, and paste/click buttons just using the html elements rather than having to load the actual web page to handle it?

Comment: If you want to "paste/click buttons" you will likely have to run an entire web browser. And given that it's SharePoint, it probably has to be IE 6 or something for that rickety mess to even barely function. A more efficient way would be to just make HTTP requests - but good luck with doing that with SharePoint.

Comment: What are you trying to scrape?  What do you mean by paste/click buttons?

Comment: we automate the creation of the sharepoint sites by inputting the sharepoint name/description/relevant info and having the app click create, all through the web browser control.  since we don't have access to the server the sharepoint is on, we wouldn't be able to use the sharepoint dll to programatically handle this

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to use a Nuget package called selenium web driver. What this package does is controls your browser (IE, Firefox, Safari, Chrome, etc) and it will act just like a web browser control. Using selenium may be just as slow as a web browser control in some instances. You mentioned using a package such as HTML agility pack; this would work but where you are wrong is in the fact that it would still be loading the page; you just dont see it.

Here is a link on how to use [selenium](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Ok7AoZceEE)